# Why aren't common magnets made of magnetite, $\rm Fe_3O_4$? Instead of ferrite, $\rm Fe_2O_3$?

Tags: physical-chemistry, magnetic-moment, ferromagnetism, chemical-compounds

Why are common, simple, cheap magnets like refrigerator magnets made (usually) of hematite ($\rm Fe_2O_3$) in some form, like 'ferrite', instead of the more magnetic and magnetizable magnetite ($\rm Fe_3O_4$)?

I am assuming cost, plus possibly chemical durability?

And, perhaps, certain ferrite(s) are longer-lasting magnetically (higher coercivity)?